# Find % Mod for floating variables

Tags: c

I'm not looking for anyone to write my code, but I am working on a homework assignment where we are supposed to make change using %. My code so far seems to work (If I input cost as 5 and amount tendered at 10, it says my change is $5 and says "$5 bills: 1"). However, the second I enter a decimal (ie: cost $5.25) my it skips the rest of the prompts and outputs a random number. Am I on the right track at all? Or could anyone possibly point me in the direction of a tutorial ?

```
 #include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int    cost,
           tender,
           change,
           twenties,
           tens,
           fives,
           ones,
           quarters,
           dimes,
           nickles,
           pennies;


    printf("Please enter cost ($): ");
    scanf("%d", &cost);

    printf("Please enter amount tendered ($): ");
    scanf("%d", &tender);

    change = tender - cost;

    printf("\nChange is $%i\n", change);

    change = ((tender - cost) * 100.0);

    twenties = change / 2000;
    printf("\n$20 bills: %i\n", twenties);

    change = change % 2000;
    tens =  change / 1000;
    printf("$10 bills: %i\n", tens);

    change = change % 1000;
    fives = change / 500;
    printf("$5 bills: %i\n", fives);

    change = change % 500;
    ones = change / 100;
    printf("$1 bills: %i\n", ones);

    change = change % 100;
    quarters = change / 25;
    printf("Quarters: %i\n", quarters);

    change = change % 25;
    dimes = change / 10;
    printf("Dimes: %i\n", dimes);

    change = change % 10;
    nickles = change / 5;
    printf("Nickles: %i\n", nickles);

    change = change % 5;
    pennies = change / 1;
    printf("Pennies: %i\n", pennies);


return (0);
}
```

Comment: Read documentation about input and storage of various numeric formats

Comment: You're inputing a cost of 5.25, and scanning it as `%d`  to an `int`, `cost`. Everything past, and including the decimal point is not read, as it is not part of a valid `int`. Further, when you then ask to read `tendered`, that read outright fails because of the leading `.` still stuck in the input buffer. Therefore the remainder of your code logic uses a bogus `cost` and `tendered` that is indeterminate. And **all** of this would be detectable if you **checked your input success/failure state**. Assumption is the mother of all....

Comment: you have to use floats with %f for decimals

Comment: Please add `\n` at end of every `printf` format string. Then, compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). And **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: @user1627167 floats don't work with %

Comment: @Celeste see this code it looks like it works http://ideone.com/LR5EgX

Comment: @user1627167 that code doesn't use % mod to find remainder?

Comment: @Celeste fmod function do this job. I don't think question heading is correct it should be how to find mod for floating variables. And since you have not declared any float why would you want to find remainder of float??

Comment: @user1627167 thanks, I will change title. I tried declaring some floats (cost and tender) which worked, however I still ended up with a wrong number for change (for example, if cost = 5.25 and tender = 10.0 output would be $4, ones= 4 quarters = 3, which should be $4.75, ones= 4 quarters = 3). So I thought it might have been something else needing tweaking. Still very new to this, this is my first computer class.

Comment: @Celeste, Well, I've provided a nice link to `fmod()` if you need any reference and also shown some changes to your code in my answer ( although I haven't fixed the logical errors which produce wrong answers as I'm not familiar with this currency )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad idea working with `float` because you get rounding errors. As this example shows you will be often short changing the customer by a penny. There are ways round the problem, but it is simply easier and more precise to work in integer pennies.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define DENOMINATIONS 8
char *names[DENOMINATIONS] = {"twenties","tens","fives","ones",
                              "quarters","dimes","nickels","pennies"};
float values[DENOMINATIONS]= {20.0f, 10.0f, 5.0f, 1.0f, 
                              0.25f, 0.10f, 0.05f, 0.01f };

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    int k;
    float change = 1.01f, number;
    printf ("Make %.2f change:\n", change);
    for (k=0; k<DENOMINATIONS; k++) {
        number = change / values[k];
        printf ("%-10s %10f %5d\n", names[k], number, (int)number);
        change = fmodf (change, values[k]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Make 1.01 change:
twenties     0.050500     0
tens         0.101000     0
fives        0.202000     0
ones         1.010000     1
quarters     0.040000     0
dimes        0.100000     0
nickels      0.200000     0
pennies      0.999999     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare All your variables with `float` instead of `int`.

In `printf` and `scanf` use `%f` instead of `%d` as format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared as `int` cannot hold decimal values, the decimal part is ignored. When you try to read decimals for an `int` using `scanf()`, the decimal part remains in your buffer and causes a lot of problems in your program. To store decimal values as well, make them `double` ( or float ) . That is, for double, use

```
  double   cost,
           tender,
           change,
           twenties,
           tens,
           fives,
           ones,
           quarters,
           dimes,
           nickles,
           pennies;
```

Also, in your `scanf()` and `printf()`, use `%lf` instead of `%d`.For example

```
scanf("%lf", &cost);
```

But then, as @Weather Vane indicated, use `fmod()` instead of `%` as `%` won't work with floating point values. Here is how

```
change = fmod(change,2000);
```

Like that, change all your `%` to `fmod()`.
To learn more about `fmod()` visit [fmod()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fmod.htm).

## EDIT

Just adding that `float` will also work for `fmod()`. In your `printf()` and `scanf()`, use `%f` for float

Comment: No, because the mod operator `%` will not work on floats. Use `fmod()`

Comment: Yikes.... Didn't notice that part. Thanks for notifying me @Weather Vane. But can I ask you for some help ? Please help me as I don't know how to use `fmod()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane that was the exact issue I was having! The % wouldn't work with floats. I've tried floating just cost and tender, too, but then change is displayed as a whole #. (ie: $4, but it will still state $1: 4, quarters: 3) I will try fmod() thanks!

Comment: @Arun this took me a couple of seconds to find: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20dckbeh.aspx You will see there is a `double` and a `float` version.

Comment: Well, I did some searching of my own and found [fmod()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fmod.htm)

Comment: `float fmodf(float x, float y));`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Weather Vane, I've edited my answer. Please check if it is correct now.

Comment: I don't think so, please see my answer.

Comment: @Weather Vane, I'm not familiar with the currency, so I can't help in fixing logical errors for this code. I'm asking if the format of `fmod()` that I have specified is correct and if there is any improvement that can be made.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are declared as `int`s. `Int` can only store whole numbers, so if you input a decimal value, it can obviously not be stored in an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You try to put float numbers in int type variable? No wonder it works weird.
Try to declare your input variables as double or float.
Also, change  `scanf("%d", &cost)` to `scanf("%f", &cost)`

Answer (score 0):

The following code allows the user to enter numbers with a decimal point, and computes an integer `amount` in cents. It's not perfect (more error checking could be added), but it will work with the remainder of your code.

```
int main( void )
{
    int dollars, cents, count, amount;
    count = scanf( "%d.%d", &dollars, &cents );

    if ( count == 1 )
        amount = dollars * 100;
    else if ( count == 2 && cents < 100 )
        amount = dollars * 100 + cents;
    else
        amount = 0;

    printf( "%d\n", amount );
}
```